# Для чего нужна строчка System.out.println(); - (а точнее почему она пустая?)

Tags: java

```
public class Matrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int w = 1; w < 10; w++) {
            for (int q = 1; q < 10; q++) {
                System.out.print(q * w + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Небольшое замечание. Объяснение в принятом вами ответе не совсем корректно. Более того, для Windows и MacOS(классической, до 9 версии) оно не верно. Если совсем простые аналогии приводить, то println осуществляет "виртуальное нажатие кнопки enter". Т.е. в *nix системах он печатает "\n", в windows "\r\n" в старых MacOS "\r". Игнорирование данного нюанса приводит к проблемам крайне редко, но при этом крайне болезненно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это строчка

```
System.out.println();
```

выводит символ новой строки, тем самым осуществляя переход на новую строку.

К примеру, вы могли бы записать

```
System.out.println( "" );
```

Эти два вызова функции, фактически, эквивалентны.

То же самое вы могли бы достичь, используя функцию `print`. Например,

```
System.out.print( "\n" );
```

Comment: Это как понимать символ новой строки? Т.е. тот вывод который находиться в области видимости второго цикла, строит строку для столба 1. А этот получается строит столбы?

Comment: Насколько я помню из чтения мною книги по C++ то там сказано что пока второй цикл не завершит свой цикл то внешний не сдвинется на указанную в цикле позицию.

Comment: @HelloGoogle Во внутреннем цикле данные выводятся в одну строку сразу же друг за другом. После этого цикла функция println осуществляет перевод на новую строку, помещая в выходной поток символ '\n', который потоком рассматривается как управляющий символ, которой говорит о том, что курсор нужно перевести на новую строку.

Comment: То есть в дальнейшем если использовать пустой вывод это всегда будет означать ( "\n" ); ?

Comment: небольшое замечание. print("\n") не является аналогом println(), т.к. последний использует системное свойство "line.separator" которое может изменяться в зависимости от платформы.

Comment: @HelloGoogle Да, функыия println так перегружена, что при отсутствии аргумента она просто осуществляет переход на новую строку, что эквивалентно вызову print( "\n" ); ,

Comment: Спасибо, что ликвидировали мой пробел :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow как уже заметили выше - println НЕ ЭКВИВАЛЕНТЕН print("\n").

Comment: @rjhdby Для описания того, что делает функция, вполне достаточно этих примеров.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow вы делаете странные допущения и вводите человека в заблуждение. Может быть на текущей платформе и ос это прокатывает, но этот код не портабельный.